# How to hide an element of dynamic table in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

I have a table and i have generated columns and rows dynamically.

This is my **table.component.html**

```
  <table id="tabella" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of _object.keys(utenti[0]); let i = index"> {{header}}</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of utenti">

        <th *ngFor="let utente of _object.keys(row)">{{row[utente]}}</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and this my **table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetUtentiService } from '../../services/getutenti.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-utente',
  templateUrl: 'utente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./utente.component.css']
})
export class UtenteComponent implements OnInit {

   utenti: any;
   _object = Object;
  visibile: boolean;



  constructor(private _getutentiService: GetUtentiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Richiamo la funzione definita nel service che effettua una get sul database

    this._getutentiService.getUtenti().subscribe(response => {
      this.utenti = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

this is my service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetUtentiService {

  private url: string = 'http://localhost:56493/Server/GetUtente';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUtenti() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

Now i want to have control of single cells of my table. I'm trying to hide only ID's column but in this code i'm not able to say "Hide this column if is ID", or i want to format date in dd/mm/yyyy instead of yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss but, again, i have to manage the single cell of my table.

How can i do these changes to my code?

Comment: How are the hidden columns going to be chosen? By the user, by your code, by something else?

Comment: I got in my Database a property called "Hidden_ID", i don't want to show it to the client, but i want to make my code general, so i prefer to make my table dynamically and not to specify for each rows {{user.First_name}}, {{user.Last_name}} etc.

Comment: How does your component know which columns should be hidden?

Comment: That's my problem. I've tried to set a boolean variable and set this to true when this._object.keys(utenti[0]).includes('Hidden_ID') and it works, but i don't know how to hide only this column in html

Comment: That's not really my question. How are the hidden columns defined in the database? And how are you currently retrieving that information in your app?

Comment: If the information about which columns should be hidden isn't in your app then your component has no hope of making a decision about which columns to hide.

Comment: I am taking informations from service that makes an http.get request to my server. The hidden columns is an int that can be NULL, but i want to upload it in my app but don't make it visible.

Comment: This is very relevant to your question. Can you add the code that gets the hidden columns, and how the columns relate to your objects. Secondly, no data is truly private in front-end frameworks, so I hope that you're only hiding columns for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: Yes, is just for aesthetic purposes.

`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetUtentiService {

  private url: string = 'http://localhost:56493/Server/GetUtente';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUtenti() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}`

This is my service.

Comment: Can you add code to the question. And it's still not clear which columns should be hidden?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209327/discussion-between-paolo-paolini-and-kurt-hamilton).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two problems. If I've correctly understood, you need :

- To add a classname like `cell-id` to the ID cell,
- Change your date format from `yyyy/mm/dd` to `dd/mm/yyyy`

If it's exact, could you try this :

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of utenti">
    <th *ngFor="let utente of _object.keys(row)"
      [ngClass]="{'cell-id': row[utente] === 'id'}">
        {{row[utente]}}
    </th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

For your second problem, have you tried with [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) ?

Comment: My problem is that i don't know ho to control my table if i build it dynamically.

Before i used `<table id="tabella" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">Cognome</th>
      <th scope="col">Numero</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let utente of utenti">
      <th scope="row">{{utente.ID}}</th>
      <td>{{utente.NOME}}</td>
      <td>{{utente.LAST_NAME}}</td>
      <td>{{utente.NUMERO}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`

Comment: And with this code i was able to modify one row, i could say "Ok, now i want to hide ID column so just add hidden property to this column" or "Ok, i want to modify css to this column, just add scope to that row".

Now i've tried to build my table dynamically because i want to make my code more general and usable with all databases, but now i don't have a <td> for each columns and rows, but just one that use *ngFor.. i hope that now my problem is less confused.